# Keeping per user screen resolution in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution

Is there away to keep individual users screen resolution in windows 8.1?

I want to keep my screen resolution at the maximum 1980x1080, but another user needs 1280x720.

TIA

Comment: this is only possible with a 3rd party tool: http://thesz.diecru.eu/content/carroll.php

Comment: Yeah saw that and the site doesn't look legit.  Low trust of what's it's doing.  Seems like a registry hack and installer.

Comment: Why do you think it has low trust?

Comment: Doesn't tell me anything about who or where they are based.  they didn't explain or show me source code just ask to trust and give me loads of options for installing

Comment: if the tool is not opensource you don't get the source code. In this case you can't use any non opensource tools. Why do you trust Windows 8.1?

Comment: Why would you trust one person in a room somewhere releasing software?  Open source works because you can if you want inspect the code before you trust it.

Comment: I don't know any other tool which does this. Trust the software or not.